# .NET WinForms - "Back" button

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, winforms

I'm coding something that works kinda like a Wizard, but I'm not sure about how to do it.

I have multiple forms. Each one does something different that depends on the data from the previous form. There is a "Master Form" that gets the input from each one and passes it to another. Normally I'd just use form.ShowDialog(), wait for input, instantiate the next form and repeat. However, this time the user needs to go back to the previous form every once in a while.

I've coded something very very simple with "GoTo" statements so you can understand the problem. Yes, it works, but I wonder if there is a better way to do it. I've been stuck in this problem for a while, so any help would be very much appreciated!

TestForm:

```
Public Class TestForm
    Public Property Result As Object

    Public Sub New(data As Object)
        InitializeComponent()
        DoSomethingWithData(data)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoSomethingWithData(data As Object)
        Result = "something"
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MasterForm
    Inherits Form

    Public Sub New()
        Dim button As New Button()
        AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf Start

        Controls.Add(button)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Step1:
        Dim testForm1 = New TestForm("rainbows")
        If testForm1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel Then
            Return
        End If

        Step2:
        Dim testForm2 = New TestForm(testForm1.Result)
        If testForm2.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel Then
            GoTo Step1
        End If

        Step3:
        Dim testForm3 = new TestForm(testForm2.Result)
        If testForm3.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel Then
            Goto Step2
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Forms can be embedded into containers on another form. The way I would tackle this is to instantiate all each form in turn when the page is landed on, but then leave them in memory until the user finishes the wizard. Back can then be a simple case of hiding the current form on the panel and showing the previous one. The problem here is your logic is sequential instead of being more like a state machine of what the wizard is currently doing, changed by what the user chooses to do.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of individual forms, you could put the controls from each form onto individual tabs or in a user control on each tab in a tabcontrol hosted in a single form.  You could then control enabling/disabling tabs as you desire based on progress through the wizard.  For example, maybe you want to let them go back to any previous tab, but they can only go sequentially forward.

Two advantages of this design:

- You have a common container for shared data, but have still hidden that information from the rest of the code.
- The tab titles can act as a form of bread crumbs to show progress through the  wizard.

Comment: Then instead of forms I'd use UserControls and instead of constructors I'd use properties. Yup, this one is good, but it seems a little bit harder to maintain. I'll try and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I should have been clearer, you are right you can use user controls on the tabs or just put the controls from the forms on the individual tab pages.  There will be a little more overhead for the flow, but it will be easier to manage form lifetime since you only have one form vs many forms being passed back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

With every successive form you open, pass the current form object as a parameter to the new form constructor and then call the `ShowDialog()` of the new form and **`Hide()`** the form only. This being done, you always have the object of the previous form which you can use to go back to by using a **"Go Back"** button which just shows the previous form using `formPrev.Show()`. So in the first place, do remember to `Hide()` the form instead of `Close()`-ing it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's actually a good idea, but then I won't be able to move forward after going back. Let's say I use `formPrev.Show()` and then `formCurrent.Hide()` , how would `formPrev` know what to do when the user presses **"Next"**?

Comment: Yes. If you go back and then press **Next**, you might just spawn a new `formCurrent` and your data there might not be still present. Well this clearly means you'll have to form a doubly-linked list of forms. One way movement ,as I said, can be easily done through constructors. For the other one, make a `public static` method to collect the `formCurrent` and hold it in a `Form` variable in your `formPrev` while going back. Keep a bool which when true would create a new form on pressing **Next** the first time but every time after that would call a method which does `recievedFormNext.Show()`.